# pandas: New column by combining numbers of two columns as strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to combine the two columns 'Day/Night?' and 'Abbreviated' as strings to get another column that displays the numbers in the form of the 'Abbreviated' value, followed by the 'Day/Night?' value.

The DataFrame I currently have:

```
    Route       Date        Collection Type Tonnage Day/Night?  Abbreviated
0   321-2_2     2014-07-11  2               12.96   2           1107
0   325-1_1     2014-07-14  1               1.85    1           1407
1   321-323_2   2014-07-14  1               4.42    2           1407
1   325-2_1     2014-07-15  3               13.20   1           1507
2   321-2_2     2014-07-15  1               3.25    2           1507
```

For example, I would have the extra column output as:

```
11072
14071
14072
15071
15072
```

I have tried this code:

```
daily['New'] = daily['Abbreviated']+str(daily['Day/Night?'])
```

where Daily is the name of the DF.

The output is strange though:

```
New
11070 2\n0 1\n1 2\n1 1\n2 ...
14070 2\n0 1\n1 2\n1 1\n2 ...
14070 2\n0 1\n1 2\n1 1\n2 ...
15070 2\n0 1\n1 2\n1 1\n2 ...
15070 2\n0 1\n1 2\n1 1\n2 ...
```

Does anyone have any advice on how I could do this?

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `astype` for type conversion:

```
df['Abbreviated'].astype(str) + df['Day/Night?'].astype(str)

#0    11072
#0    14071
#1    14072
#1    15071
#2    15072
#dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cols = ['Abbreviated', 'Day/Night?']
df.assign(New=df[cols].astype(str).apply(''.join, 1))

   Route       Date  Collection  Type  Tonnage  Day/Night?  Abbreviated    New
0      0    321-2_2  2014-07-11     2    12.96           2         1107  11072
1      0    325-1_1  2014-07-14     1     1.85           1         1407  14071
2      1  321-323_2  2014-07-14     1     4.42           2         1407  14072
3      1    325-2_1  2014-07-15     3    13.20           1         1507  15071
4      2    321-2_2  2014-07-15     1     3.25           2         1507  15072
```